# return biggest/highest object from jquery elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, size, height

Howdey!

Let's take a look at the following jQuery function:

```
$.fn.getMax = function() {
    return this.height(Math.max.apply(this, $(this).map(function(i, e) {
        return $(e).height();
    }).get()));
};
```

It returns and sets the heighest height for all selectors. But what is, if you want to return the `object` (not the height) with the heighest value?

So if you call the function like this:

```
$(selector).getMax().css({backgroundColor: "indigo"});
```

...how the element with the heighest height gets the `backgroundColor`?

**UPDATE**

I've managed it now with `$.makeArray`, as [Amareswar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322582/return-biggest-heighest-object-from-jquery-elements#comment18174292_13322582) said it.

```
$.fn.getMax = function(prop) {
    var max = $.makeArray($(this)).sort(function(a, b) {
        return (parseInt($(b).css(prop), 10) || 1) - (parseInt($(a).css(prop), 10) || 1);
    }).shift();
    return $(max);
};
```

Cheers!

Comment: You haven't asked a question...simply provided some code that makes no sense

Comment: 'return this' as the last statement

Comment: @charlietfl Added `how` and `?` ;-)

Comment: @Amareswar `return this`, does not do the trick.

Comment: In that case you should write a static function like $.makeArray by passing the elements as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.fn.getMax = function() {
     /* create array of heights*/
    var heights = $(this).map(function(i, e) {
        return $(e).height();
    }).get();
    /* get max height*/
    var max = Math.max.apply(this, heights);
    /* get index of max in array*/
    var pos = $.inArray(max, heights)
    /* return element with proper index*/
    return this.eq(pos);
};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/tTuE7/

EDIT : assumes you only want one element returned

Comment: Nice approach, but I've managed it now like Amareswar said. However, thanks! :-*