# jQuery - getting the height of the highest element

Tags: jquery, arrays, height

Let's say I've got a bunch of unsorted list with different, dynamically heights (depends on how much elements are in the list).
How do I get the height of the highest one?

I've already tried getting the goal with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322582/return-biggest-highest-object-from-jquery-elements) post.

so this is what I've been trying (the red background color just to see if it is working)

```
    $.fn.getMax = function() {
     /* create array of heights*/
    var heights = $(this).map(function(i, e) {
        return $(e).height();
    }).get();
    /* get max height*/
    var max = Math.max.apply(this, heights);
    /* get index of max in array*/
    var pos = $.inArray(max, heights)
    /* return element with proper index*/
    return this.eq(pos);
};

$('.navi-main li').getMax().css({backgroundColor: "red"});
```

Comment: post your html code...

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far.. it may happened that you have not followed the reference post correctly or there may be some error.

Comment: sorry guys, just added some code

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
var max = -1;
$('.navi-main li').each(function() {
    max = Math.max(max, $(this).height());
});
alert(max);
```

or as a one-liner:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.navi-main li').map(function() { return $(this).height(); }));
alert(max);
```

;